# What is the difference between the __int__ and __index__ methods in Python 3?

Tags: python, casting

[The Data Model section of the Python 3.2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/reference/datamodel.html) provides the following descriptions for the `__int__` and `__index__` methods:

> #### `object.__int__(self)`
>
> Called to implement the built-in [function `int()`]. Should return [an integer].
>
> #### `object.__index__(self)`
>
> Called to implement `operator.index()`. Also called whenever Python needs an integer object (such as in slicing, or in the built-in `bin()`, `hex()` and `oct()` functions). Must return an integer.

I understand that they're used for different purposes, but I've been unable to figure out why two different methods are necessary. What is the difference between these methods? Is it safe to just alias `__index__ = __int__` in my classes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [PEP 357](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/): Allowing Any Object to be Used for Slicing.

> The `nb_int` method is used for coercion and so means something
>   fundamentally different than what is requested here.  This PEP
>   proposes a method for something that *can* already be thought of as
>   an integer communicate that information to Python when it needs an
>   integer.  The biggest example of why using `nb_int` would be a bad
>   thing is that float objects already define the `nb_int` method, but
>   float objects *should not* be used as indexes in a sequence.

*Edit*: It seems that it was implemented in Python 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll find the answer in [PEP 357](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/), which has this abstract:

> This PEP proposes adding an nb_index
>   slot in PyNumberMethods and an
>   __index__ special method so that arbitrary objects can be used
>   whenever integers are explicitly needed in Python, such as in slice
>   syntax (from which the slot gets its name).

Comment: This does not explain why you can't just use `__int__`