# What is a "SupportsIndex"?

Tags: python, python-typing

I was reading the Python doc for typing and annotations, and I found a protocol named [`SupportsIndex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.SupportsIndex).

Is this a special type for indexage in lists?

I tried using it in a code in case it would raise any warning :

```
def __get_color_index(color: str) -> SupportsIndex:
    color_index: SupportsIndex = 0
    match color:
        case 'red':
            color_index = 0
        case 'green':
            color_index = 1
        case 'blue':
            color_index = 2
        case 'magenta':
            color_index = 3
        case 'yellow':
            color_index = 4
        case 'cyan':
            color_index = 5
    return color_index

def add_color(colors: List[bool], color: str):
    colors[__get_color_index(color)] = True
```

I don't get any warning with this code, so the question is :
Is it better for any reason to use the type `SupportsIndex` instead of  type `int`?

**Edit :**
So, if someone is still wondering, the `SupportsIndex` type checks at runtime if the object passed does have a method `__index__` and raises a `TypeError` otherwise.

Comment: Look at the PR description - https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/13448

Comment: For reference: [`object.__index__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the \_\_int\_\_ and \_\_index\_\_ methods in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898310/what-is-the-difference-between-the-int-and-index-methods-in-python-3)

Comment: I don't understand why you expect this code to result in a warning/error in the first place. It *does* return a valid index as promised.